# File sharing resource is online but not working

Tags: windows, file-sharing, smb, windows-server-2016, windows-error-reporting

I have a Windows Server 2016 that needs to access a file share on a Netapp. I checked all firewall rules so the connection is allowed and I can see the system accessing the file share on port 445.

In the screenshot you can see the error message, all other systems can connect to the fileshare. So I can exclude an error on the fileshare.

[image]

Do you have any advice?

Comment: I would suggest you could disable windows firewall temporarily to see if the issue still existed. If yes, is there any security software of third party firewall which might block the traffic in your environment?

Comment: Local firewall is deaktivated. There are several firewalls in between but I can see on the firewalls that the traffic reaches the destination server on port 445. So I am pretty sure this ist not the reason